# PayPal iOS SDK - Fee Charged Query

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

In our application, we are utilizing PayPal iOS SDK for payments.

However, we are being charged a fees which we cannot understand.

For ex: If one person has to pay other one $ 10 as part of the transaction, he is being charged $ 10.80.

This fee is not usually charged if accounts are linked to a checkings account and the transaction is carried out outside iOS.

Is this standard fee for utilizing Paypal in iOS ?

Comment: There are fees when using credit card (free when using paypal credit) and they are charged even in paypal site. Cannot avoid that. This 0.8$ may and will increase if you will transfer greater amounts of money.

Answer (score 0):

As PayPal states:

Free to transfer

There’s no fee to send money to friends and family when you link a bank account or use your PayPal balance. When you use a debit or credit card, there is a flat fee of 2.9% + $0.30 per transaction. You can also send money internationally for a small fee.

This cannot be avoided.

Since this is correct but does not target PayPal mobile SDK i will update my answer with this SDK-specific info about taxes:

Fees vary per country. For Purchase Payments, which include payments processed using the REST APIs or PayPal Mobile SDK, PayPal U.S. charges 2.9% or less, plus $0.30 per transaction. Volume discounts are also available. There are no setup fees and no cancellation fees. PayPal is free for your buyers. You can read more about PayPal's fees.

This ofcourse was taken from PayPal FAQ:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq

Comment: If you would go to your paypal account and try to transfer exact same amount to same receiver with same method, you should see why and what kind of taxes you have to pay.

Comment: There are no taxes or anything else involved when I am using my Paypal account for this same transaction outside the mobile app. However, as soon as I do the same transaction inside the iOS, it charges me a fees.Appreciate any help...

Comment: As i updated my answer, PayPal clearly states that even if PayPal transaction made in-site is free, using Mobile SDK it WILL cost ya (or user).